# Starting a CMD from Windows Shortcut

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, shortcut

I am using a shortcut in Windows to start a cmd and I am then using this to open another file. The code I am using is:

%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start "program name"

This works fine but I would really like the shortcut to not have the cmd window pop up and then start the program. Is there some way I can open the cmd window silently in the background and run the file without me having to see it?

Comment: you mean like what virus usually does?

Comment: why don't just call `%programname%`

Comment: You can do it with vbscript so you should add the tag of vbscript

Answer (score 1):

This a **Hybrid Script [Bat/VBS]** to create a shortcut on the desktop of your **calc.exe**

```
@echo off
mode con cols=87 lines=5 & color 9B
Title Generer le vbscript pour la creation du raccourci sur le bureau by Hackoo
echo Generer le vbscript pour la creation du raccourci
Timeout /T 2 > Nul
(
echo Call Shortcut("c:\windows\system32\calc.exe","Calculatrice"^)
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************^)
echo Sub Shortcut(CheminApplication,Nom^)
echo    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
echo    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
echo    MyTab = Split^(CheminApplication,"\"^)
echo    If Nom = "" Then
echo    Nom = MyTab(UBound^(MyTab^)^)
echo    End if
echo    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
echo    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath ^& "\" ^& Nom ^& ".lnk"^)
echo    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote^(CheminApplication^)
echo    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "Winver.exe,0"
echo    objShortCut.Save
echo End Sub
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
echo ^'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
echo Function DblQuote(Str^)
echo    DblQuote = Chr(34^) ^& Str ^& Chr^(34^)
echo End Function
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
) > Shortcutme.vbs
echo Execution du vbscript pour la creation du raccourci de la calculatrice sur le bureau
Start /Wait Shortcutme.vbs
echo Suppression du Vbscript
Del Shortcutme.vbs
echo Termine
Pause > Nul
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and shortest solution for running a batch file without opening the DOS window is using a VBS Script to call the batch file. Create a `.vbs` file with following lines

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "<your-batch-file-name>" & Chr(34), 0 
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

here batch-file-name have to be within double quote e.g. "new.bat"

And the batch file contains those lines

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start "program name"
```